# How to write a generic function that takes a lambda with a default argument?

Tags: c++, function, generics, lambda, default-value

I want to store a function in a variable. I have a generic setter function to assign it. If no function is specified I want to use a default function. How do I accomplish this?

My code so far:

```
void(*fmain)();

template <typename Func>
void setFunc(Func f = [](){cout << "Working!" << endl;}){
    fmain = f;
}

int main(){
    setFunc();

    fmain();
}
```

Comment: Why make the function a template to begin with when the argument needs to be implicitly convertible to `void(*)()` anyways?

Comment: Good point. I didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supply both default template parameter and (matching) default function parameter:

```
void default_action(void) {cout << "Working!" << endl;};

template <typename Func = void ( * )(void)>
void setFunc(Func f = &default_action){
    fmain = f;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I replaced default_action with a lambda but it worked exactly like I wanted. However I have to be mindful that the function I pass is the same type as fmain. Is there a way to make that generic too? Thank you

Comment: Come to think of it as long as fmain is a void, this template can never be generic can it??

Comment: @user678253 Modifying `fmain` declaration can make it generic: `::std::function<void (void)> fmain;`.

Comment: Isnt that the same thing though? If I gave it a lambda that returns an int it would break right? I have a feeling its not possible. Unless there was such thing as a generic return type.

Comment: @user678253 Storing (and invoking later) any callable objects with different signatures in the same variable is a different question.

Comment: True. And its not important to me atm. Ill google it later. Thanks for the help.